# How to retrieve JSON data into Laravel and display it's elements on the view?

Tags: laravel

I installed a package (https://github.com/kirill-latish/laravel-newsapi).

And after setting everything up and also everything in the controller like so:

```
public function newsapi(){
  $response = NewsAPI::topHeadlines()->get([
        'country' => 'gb',
        'category'=>'sports'
    ]);
  return view('newsapi', compact('response'));
}
```

and then added into the view:

```
{{ $response }}
```

i'm getting a:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

How can i work this? And also besides retrieving all the json, how can i display the things normally in a view? such as the title of the news article and url?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you give the full line where the $response is inserted in the view? Possibly you need to use {!! $response !!} to escape content. Can you also confirm $response is a string? Looking something like '{"key": "value"}' ??

Comment: `{{ }}` in blade uses to `echo()`. so to `echo()` it should be a 'String'

Comment: Debug it's structure. Put `dd($response);` before `return` statement to see how object's structure looks like (and what keys you need from there). Post structure here too if you have further doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

In controller:

```
$response = NewsAPI::topHeadlines()->get([
              'country' => 'us',
              'category'=>'technology'
          ]);
$articles = $response->articles;
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
{{ $article->title }}
@endforeach
```